# MMC could not create the snap-in. SQL Server configuration manager error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-config-manager

When i tried to connect to sql server configuration manager in sql server 2008. `It shows error MMC could not create the snap-in.`

It was working perfectly till last night. What can be the reason, how can i solve it. I can not post image of error because of low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out that it was an issue with .net framework.

I downloaded this file: "dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" from Microsoft website, and used the "repair" option. It worked for me. Hope it helps.