# MMC could not created the snap-in SQL Server configuration manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, mmc, snap-in

When i tried to connect to sql server configuration manager in sql server 2008. It shows error MMC could not create the snap-in.
[image: Error Image]

It was working perfectly till last night. What can be the reason, how can i solve it. But in background sql server is working perfect.

Comment: did you fixed this problem?

Answer (score 4):

***Note:** *Before doing this, make sure that your user has Administrative righs to run MMC, unless it's not Administrator, below procedure won't work.*

1. **Win button + R**,  then type **mmc** and press enter.
2. Choose **File->Add/Remove Snap-in**.
3. Click **Add** to Console Root
4. and find the **"SQL Server Configuration Manager"**

You will be able to use it from there or replace existing console by saving it to bin folder of you SQL server's installation.

*Note: This is the only option that really worked for me...*

Comment: I am not able to find SQL Server Configuration Manager under the Available-Snap ins. What could be the problem?

Comment: Is it installed? Is your user having proper rights?

Comment: Yes, it is installed and have selected Windows Authentication.

Comment: Yeah, but is your windows user having admin rights?

Answer (score 2):

This guy here had the same problem: [MMC could not create the snap-in. SQL Server configuration manager error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599563/mmc-could-not-create-the-snap-in-sql-server-configuration-manager-error/27554070)

I said there that I had the same problem and found out that it was an issue with .net framework.

I downloaded this file: "dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" from Microsoft website, and used the "repair" option. It worked for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run SQL Server Installation and Repair your SQL Server. It works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using Server 2022 and installed SQL Express 2022 and had the same issue. Reloading c++ 2017 redistributable software corrected the issue.