# How to solve MMC could not create the snap-in. SQL Server Configuration Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server

MMC could not create the snap-in.
MMC could not create the snap-in. The snap-in might not have been installed correctly.
Name: SQL Server Configuration Manager
CLSID:{D52E5F54-75D9-4A93-91B7-2215EA5CBED2}

I uninstalled SQL Server 2008 and install SQL Server 2012, but when I open SQL Server Configuration Manager, I got above error message.

**I tried to use the following link where I created Console1 file but from there I do know what's next, the file was created called Console1**
[MMC could not created the snap-in SQL Server configuration manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756980/mmc-could-not-created-the-snap-in-sql-server-configuration-manager)
Where can i put that file of console1 I created?

How can I solve it?
Please anyone can help me

Comment: open the sql2012 configuration manager directly from:  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager11.msc . do you get the same error?

Comment: No, SQLServerManager11.msc works fine, except SQLServerManager10.msc is the one which has same error

Comment: SQLServerManager10.msc comes with sql2008 and you have uninstalled sql2008. You do not need SQLServerManager10.msc at all, just use SQLServerManager11 (newer versions of manager can handle older sql instances/versions but not the other way around)